# How to plot coordinates (1,2) against time (0.5) in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot vehicle position (coordinates - x,y) against time(1s,2s,3s...). I tried with `matplotlib` but could not succeed. I am new in python. Could anyone help me please.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

coordinate = [[524.447876,1399.091919], [525.1377563,1399.95105], [525.7932739,1400.767578], [526.4627686,1401.601563],
     [527.2360229,1402.564575], [527.8989258,1403.390381], [528.5689697,1404.224854]]

timestamp =[0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3]

plt.plot(coordinate,timestamp)
```

Plot comes like: But this is wrong one. I did wrong.

[image]

Plot supposed to become, in particular, timestamp (1s) the vehicle position is (x,y). So there should be one line just like vehicle trajectory.

Thanks.

Comment: So, are you trying to make a 3D plot?

Comment: No, 2D plotting. My main goal is reading data from panda for several vehicles (coordinates and time) and then plot it, so it will be looks like trajectory (just like line graph). Maybe I am wrong, can I do it in 2D format or I have to go for 3D. Could you please suggest.

Comment: Basically you have three axis there, so I don't think you can plot that on 2d anymore, for x, y , time you need three axes! I believe the best you can achieve if you don't wana to 3d, it will be velocity vs time graph, but I don't know about your requirements so you have to figure that out yourself!!

Comment: well, x, y and time makes 3 dimensions total. In this case you cant display 3 dimensions in 2-dimensional plot. Maybe you should convert (x,y) pair to distance for example?

Comment: Can you please accept an answer or tell everyone how you solved it, to help people for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the output you're looking for:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
coordinate = [[524.447876,1399.091919],
              [525.1377563,1399.95105],
              [525.7932739,1400.767578],
              [526.4627686,1401.601563],
              [527.2360229,1402.564575],
              [527.8989258,1403.390381],
              [528.5689697,1404.224854]]
v1 = [y[1] for y in coordinate]
v2 = [y[0] for y in coordinate]
x = [0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3]

plt.plot(x,v1)
plt.plot(x,v2,'--')
plt.ylim(0,1500)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one thing, so cant I show the timestamp in the figure? for example, in 0.05s the vehicle position is this ...

Comment: Do you want the timestamp on the xcor or ycor?

Comment: timestamp in xcor

Comment: Can you tell me what the x and y ticks mean in the current graph? Is it distance and speed?

Comment: x and y are the coordinates (vehicle position). I have simulation data in excel format where based on time there are position (x value and y value) of the vehicle is given. Now I want to see in the graph format that regarding time what is the vehicle position.

Comment: I am not sure here it is allowed or not. if you ok can you share your email address.

Comment: @Villen What do you mean?

Comment: I am saying, then I can share the problem more appropriately with data (excel file) and my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216142/discussion-between-villen-and-ann-zen).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the problem over here is that you are using a two-dimensional list, so matplotlib plots the coordinates and not the timestamp.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

coordinate = np.array([[524.447876,1399.091919], [525.1377563,1399.95105], [525.7932739,1400.767578], [526.4627686,1401.601563], [527.2360229,1402.564575], [527.8989258,1403.390381], [528.5689697,1404.224854]])

timestamp =np.array([0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3])

plt.plot(coordinate)
```

Output: 
[image: Output-1]

You have to convert it into a single dimension list like this:

```
coordinate_new = np.array([524.447876,525.1377563,1399.95105, 525.7932739,1400.767578, 526.4627686,1401.601563])
timestamp =np.array([0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3])
plt.plot(coordinate_new, timestamp)
```

Then the output will be: 
[image: Output-2]

Hope I could help!!

If you want to plot it in 3-d, here is what you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#importing matplotlib


fig = plt.figure() #adding figure
ax_3d = plt.axes(projection="3d") #addign 3-d axes
coordinate_x = [524.447876, 525.137756, 525.7932739, 526.4627686, 527.2360229, 527.8989258, 528.5689697]
coordinate_y = [1399.091919, 1399.95105,1400.767578,1401.601563,1402.564575,1403.390381,1404.224854]
timestamp =[0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3]

# defining the variables
ax.plot(coordinate_x, coordinate_y, timestamp)
#plotting them
```

Output:

[image: Output-3]

All the Best!

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the problem is if I convert the coordinate in one dimension then I lost y of coordinates. Only x plots there against time. Sorry if I wrongly interpret this. But I need both values of coordinates, so can plot perfectly the vehicle position based on time.

Comment: Hey, for that I believe you should make a figure object using matplotlib, then you can make two seperate arrays for the x and y coordinates and plot both of them against the time stamp on the same figure.

Answer (score 0):

Does something simple like this meet your needs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coordinates = [
    (524.447876,1399.091919),
    (525.1377563,1399.95105),
    (525.7932739,1400.767578),
    (526.4627686,1401.601563),
    (527.2360229,1402.564575),
    (527.8989258,1403.390381),
    (528.5689697,1404.224854),
]

timestamp = [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3]

x, y = zip(*coordinates)

ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot(x, y, timestamp);

plt.show()
```

[image]

Matplotlib will let you rotate the image with the mouse to view it from various angles.